# How to Save/Reload the various buttons in the UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a simple question : my user can add buttons in `UIView`. I would use `NSUserDefault` to save the various buttons and then reload them in the `UIView` at application startup (not the background) .How can I do ?

```
    -(void)AddButton:(UIButton*)sender {
         CountButton++;
           if (CountButton< 11) {
            button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            button2.frame = CGRectMake(20, 80, 120, 80);
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
            [button2 setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSString* buttonTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button%d", CountButton];
            [button2 setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSString *selectorName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ButtonAdd%d:", CountButton];

    [button2 addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString(selectorName)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}}
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you want. You want to know how to use NSUserDefault ? another thing, please try to make your code clearer (indent properly)...

Comment: I can create 10 different buttons through AddButton on my uiview. When I close my app again and the 10 buttons disappear. then my user is forced to recreate the 10 buttons.
How can I save the buttons created from my user?

Comment: check my answer or sangony's answer.. Both will work for you

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, in viewDidLoad, check the NSUserDefault value that you previously stored and programmatically create that many buttons and add them as subviews to the controller's view.

Hope that helps.

Comment: but it possibile that there no I can help ? Wanted desperately Developer with a good Heart

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults is meant for small pieces of data. Saving numerous buttons is probably not the best thing for NSUserDefaults. Consider using a file instead. You can load the file at the appropriate time in your code in order to display the saved buttons.

First create the buttons, like in your posted code:

```
button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button2.frame = CGRectMake(20, 80, 120, 80);
//etc...
```

To write the file with your buttons:

```
NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                   NSUserDomainMask,
                                                                   YES);
NSMutableString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myButton1, myButton2, myButton3, nil];
NSString *filePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserButtons"];
BOOL fileError = [myArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"User data to file successful: %@",(fileError ? @"Yes" : @"No"));
```

To read the file:

```
NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                       NSUserDomainMask,
                                                                       YES);
    NSMutableString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserButtons"];
    NSArray *fileArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
    if([fileArray count] > 0)
    {
        // place your buttons back into the view.
        // [self.view addSubview:[fileArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
```

Comment: Good idea, but I dont think that an array of 10 buttons is a lot for NSUserDefaults...

Comment: I guess it comes down to preference (pun intended). I usually operate under the rule of "Is this a preference". If yes, then I use NSUserDefaults.

Comment: What I usually do, is that if I have more than one property, field , ... I use external file, plist or core data, it depends what i need it for. But if it's one object (in this case array), with limited size (not something that will kill the memory), i use NSUserDefaults... I still consider my self new to objective-c, so please correct me if i am wrong... Thanks

Comment: You're not wrong at all. Do what works for you and try out new stuff on occasion.

Comment: i have User data to file successful : NO , but on .h file thing I must add sangony ?

Comment: and I should modify this string with
NSArray * myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: Button1, Button2, Button3, nil];

Comment: @user2244770 - Double check your code for the file write. I did a copy and paste from one of my projects. Not sure what you mean with the "h.file". Explain further if you can. The NSArray is where you insert all the buttons you want to save. You can name them whatever you want. I just used Button1, Button2, Button3 as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the buttons to an Array. Then add the array to UserDefault:

```
   NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            [userDefaults setObject:buttonArray
                             forKey:@"buttons"];
            [userDefaults synchronize];
```

on your viewDidLoad:
do this:

```
buttonsArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"buttons"];
```

Finally, loop in the array and add each button

Cheers

Comment: I HAVE User data to file successful : YES with Sangony Help but don't go !!! on my file h , thing I must add